# ZKemkeeper ReadGeneralLogData function doesn't finish

Tags: powerbuilder

We are using Powerbuilder(PowerScript) with ZKempkeeper dlls to downloading attendance data from biometric/finger scanning machines. 
We have a program for this working in Windows 7 and XP, but in Windows 10 the program freeze normally when use the function ReadGeneralLogData to read all data. Sometimes the program works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Can you mention if the win10 system is 32/64 bit configuration?
have you tried un-registering all the zkemkeeper dlls (*search registry and make sure all entries are cleared*) and registering again? in case it is 64 bit, copy the dlls into "c:\windows\syswow64" folder and register using regedit32.exe from that folder.

Comment: I do that. Windows 10 is 64 bits and i try with 32 and 64 bits